# Converting matrix to an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

How can I copy the elements from a matrix, entered by user, to an array? I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
  int main(){
  int m[20][20],a[400],c=0;//max dimensions;
  scanf("%d %d",&M,&N);//dimensions of matrix;
  for(i=0;i<M;i++{
      for(j=0;j<N;j++{
      scanf("%d", &m[i][j]);
          for(c=0;c<M*N;c++) 
          a[c]=m[i][j];
       }}}
```

Comment: The array copy needs to be done **after** all the user input is complete. That is, need to move the last `for` loop out of the existing loops and into a seperate `i`/`j` loop. If that still doesn't work for you then please describe the problem in more detail than "didn't work". Give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: That is an aconventional way of writing C code. The Pico style with multiple `}` markers on a single line is anathema in C (except, presumably, to your professor(s)). You've indented the code by miles, but don't use spaces within lines; that also makes the code harder to read. The indentation isn't consistent; that too makes it harder to read. You have two 'loops' like `for(i=0;i<M;i++{` where you've missed the `)` before the `{`. You declare `c` early, but don't declare `i` or `j` at all. It is better if you post code that can be compiled!  (The inner loop does not do what you want either.)

Comment: regarding; `scanf("%d %d",&M,&N);`  The variables `M` and `N` are not declared anywhere in the posted code.  Therefore, the posted code will not compile!

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: (the compiler will not care) 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) please follow the4 axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*   Strongly suggest treating `}` as a separate statement.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you want to store both the matrix format and the array format, but anyway here is a code that should do the trick with also the data output to show the result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define R 20 //max rows
#define C 20 //max columns

int main() {
    int m[R][C]; //matrix
    int a[R*C];  //array
    int r, c;    //user matrix size
    int i, j;    //iterators

    printf("insert row size: ");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    printf("insert column size: ");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    if(r > R || c > C) {
        printf("Invalid sizes");
        return -1;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            printf("insert value for row %d column %d: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &m[i][j]);
            a[(c * i) + j] = m[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            printf("%d ", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i = 0; i < r * c; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I also added some checks for the user data, avoiding to generate a matrix bigger that the maximum size. Also you don't need separate loops but it can be done all together.

Comment: Don't forget that users can type zero or negative numbers for the array dimensions.  Validation is hard!  And reporting the problem sensibly is hard too.  `if (r < 1 || r > R) { fprintf(stderr, "The number of rows %d is out of the range %d..%d\n", r, 1, R); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }` tells people more precisely which value was wrong and the range of acceptable values.  You might use enumerated constants `enum { MIN_ROW = 1, MAX_ROW = 20 }` and use those in the conditions and printing.  Report errors on standard error, not standard output.

Comment: Sure there is a lot more validation to be done, like: checking that the user inputs a numeric value (letters, icons and similar are invalid) for both matrix size and values; check that the introduced value does not overflow the int representation; etc. I just gave a suggestion to keep validation in mind

Comment: rather than having to verify the (user entered) values for `r` and `c`,  strongly suggest using the Variable length array feature of C.  I.E. get the values of `r` and `c` from the user, then declare the array using `r` and `c`.

Comment: Sure it is possible to use dynamic memory allocation, but I think this is more complex and out of the scope of the initial question. But I agree that would be more flexible and memory efficient (you would just allocate the minimum necessary memory for the data)